# What is the purpose of function.boolean = True in Python

Tags: python

I was looking at some python2 code that looks something like this:

```
def foo(self):
    pass

foo.boolean = 'WTH'
```

and this code seems to be syntactically correct.  But what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Of course it is *syntactically* correct, `foo.bar = baz` is correct. Anyway, function objects are like any other object, you can assign attributes to them if you'd like, just like `class Foo: pass; foo = Foo(); foo.boolean = "WTH"`, however, I can't think of a lot of non-hacky use-cases off the top of my head

Comment: `function` is one of the few (only?) builtin types that accept arbitrary attributes, though.

Comment: @chepner definitely not only, consider exceptions, for example. Built-in containers definitely, though, I think.